# How do i resolve conflict when selecting productid whose product visit have same occurences

Tags: linq, entity-framework

My Database Table Contain Records Like this:

```
ID   ProductId  Occurences
1        1          1
2        2          5
3        3          3
4        4          3
5        5          5
6        6          8
7        7          9
```

**Now i want to get top 4 ProductId with the highest Occurences**.

This is my Query:

```
 var data = (from temp in context.Product
                        orderby temp.Occurences descending
                        select temp).Take(4).ToList();
```

**Now here as because ProductId 2 and 5 have same occurences and ProductId 3 and 4 also have same occurences then here I am not getting that how to resolve this means which product id should i take as because they are having same occurences.**

Basically i am selecting this productid to display this products on my website.i will display those products which are return by this query.

So can anyone please give me some idea like how to resolve this ???

Expected Output:

```
 ID   ProductId  Occurences
 1        7         9
 2        6         8
```

**so Now for 3rd position Which ProductId i should select as because both ProductId 2 and 5 have same Occurences and for 4th position which ProductId i should select among 3 and 4 as because they both too have same occurences.**

Comment: Should you display `exactly 4 products`? or products which their occurences is in `top 4 occourences`?

Comment: I want to display Top 4 products with the highest occurences.like first ProductId 7 will come(as because it has highest occurence that is 9) and then productid 6 will come.so likewise i want to display

Comment: so **show us the expected display list**!!??

Comment: Please see my Updated question and if any suggestion related to logic any one can give me to resolve this conflict or do i need to add extra field to resolve this conflict.

Comment: so for top productid's with same occurences you need to provide an additional `order` clause OR choose some of those productids randomly with regardless the the sorting clause.

Comment: Yeah i want some kind of logic or anything to select among those productid which have same occurences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can I suggest you to use group by technique and pick the first one

```
context.Product.GroupBy(p => p.Occurance)
                       .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
                       .Take(4)ToList();
```

Sorry, I have not tested this but it should do the job. You just need to add OrderBy along with it.

Comment: But then how this will distinguish to select among productid with the same occurences??

Comment: @MariaPithia when you have same occurance level, do you want to select both or you just want to select the first one from  Project ID 3, 4?  What is your expected output ?